# Contar desde el último registro de tabla hacia atrás

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema en SQL Express que me gustaría resolver. Tengo una tabla con registro de personas que ingresan a un local comercial y con registro de la fecha y la hora. Ahora necesito sacar estadísticas de los últimos 30 días consultando hoy (GETDATE()) hacia atrás, pero al consultar, por ejemplo 21 de marzo, lo hago por el día con el 21, 20, 19, etc, lo bueno es que obtengo el número, pero lo hace desde el inicio de la tabla, es decir va a buscar el 21 pero encuentra el 21 de enero, 20 de enero, 19 de enero, etc. No se como hacer para que busque o cuente desde el último registro hacia atrás. Gracias desde a cualquiera que le haya tocado esta situación. Aquí va el string de consulta donde ya empieza a mostrar desde el día anterior al de hoy y para obtener el penúltimo día hay que cambiar el -1 por -2 y así sucesivamente:

```
SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -1,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())) AS 'Fecha',
 COUNT(CounterIndex) AS 'Cuenta'
FROM [BDCS].[dbo].[Data]
 WHERE DAY(EventTime) = DAY(DATEADD (DAY, -1, GETDATE()));
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que queres los ultimos 30 dias.. y no un mes para atras (que pueden ser un dia mas, o dos menos si estamos en febrero).

Para ello, lo que estas buscando es que el dia del evento sea mayor (o igual, eso ya queda en vos) a la fecha actual menos 30.

Por lo tanto, tu query deberia ser algo asi:

```
SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -1,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())) AS 'Fecha',
COUNT(CounterIndex) AS 'Cuenta'
FROM [BDCS].[dbo].[Data]
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, EventTime, GETDATE()) < 30
```

Notese que lo que busco ahi, es que la diferencia sea menor que 30 dias.. esos son los ultimos 30 dias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, quiere que esa consulta cuente desde el ultimo registro y no desde getdate(), para eso yo haría lo siguiente:

```
SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -1,CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME())) AS ' COUNT(CounterIndex) AS 'Cuenta'
    FROM [BDCS].[dbo].[Data]
    WHERE DAY(EventTime) = DAY(DATEADD (DAY, -1, ( **select top 1 FechaRegistro from [BDCS].[dbo].[Data] order by [BDCS].[dbo].[Data].FechaRegistro**)));
```

De manera que ordenes como quieras en la sub-select del final para contar desde el ultimo registro que quieras, ya sea por fecha o por PK